# R function similar to Stata mlogtest command

Tags: r, stata, mlogit

Is there an R function similar to the Stata command`mlogtest, combine`? It's a handy function to perform multiple Wald tests if any categories from a dependent variable in a model can be combined with each other.

Here is the documentation https://www.stata.com/stb/stb58/sg155/mlogtest.hlp

and description `^combine^ computes Wald tests of whether two outcomes in the ^mlogit^ can be combined.`

Comment: A more up-to-date help is https://jslsoc.sitehost.iu.edu/stata/spost13_ado/mlogtest.sthlp

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an answer was provided previously to compute it yourself, either manually or aided by `car::linearHypothesis`

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296921/coefficient-equality-test-for-multinomial-logit-preferably-in-r

Furthermore, {mlogit} on CRAN includes the Hausman-McFadden Test to test the IIA hypothesis (independence of irrelevant alternatives), which is the 2nd test provided by Stata's `mlogtest`

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/mlogit.pdf